# Could planet of the apes really happen?

Tags: evolution

1. Would it be possible for non-human apes such as chimpanzees,
   gorillas , and orangutans to take the place of humans?
2. Like in the 1968 movie “Planet of the apes”, would it be possible
   for apes to discover fire, agriculture and create complex
   civilization?
3. Would they be able to communicate like we do? In a few thousand
   years would it be possible for these apes to be able to travel
   through space?
4. Also, in this world could  humans take the place of modern day apes?
   Climbing in trees and those sorts of things.

Are any of these things possible? Please let me know

Comment: Too many questions in one. This make your question too broad. Please narrow it down to one single problem per question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all of that is possible, given a mutation affecting the brain (in Planet of the Apes the mutation was induced by genetic engineering into an ape).

The body forms do not make a difference, all that matters is a brain that can solve problems like people do. None of the common things people tell you are necessary are *actually* necessary: They don't need opposable thumbs, they don't need to walk upright, they don't need particular biological features of humans.

Chimps and gorillas already make tools and have been known to use weapons like rocks and sticks.

The only unique thing about humans is our mental life, the ability to plan more than a few hours in advance, to model physics and behavior, to think abstractly and recursively. Only the human brain, to our knowledge, can make a plan that will take years and thousands of people and will actually work (e.g. to make a pyramid, divert a river, build a city).

The evidence we have thus far is scant, but this ability appears to have been due to a singular mutation that occurred perhaps 200,000 years ago, by chance. It would spread like wildfire, especially once passed along to a male: As the only smart ape in the world they would be able to mate more or less at will and defeat all rivals with very simple plans.

The odds of a mutation like that occurring again, but in a modern ape, are slim but not impossible. However, genetically engineering an ape to have a human brain is entirely plausible, putting motivations for doing so aside.

4) Humans can live naked in the wild and in trees without a problem and easily. Some do already. To remain there instead of building villages, shelters, traps, boats, etc, you would have to make them brain damaged in some way. Otherwise their human intellect will work every day to make their life take less work, be less dangerous, to invent weapons, to store calories in some way to be less dependent on the vagaries of nature, etc.

Comment: They already *have* opposable thumbs, they already *can* walk upright (and quite often do)...

Comment: @AlexP It is not their preferred method of locomotion, like it is for humans, and their hips are not evolved to walk long term, like humans. Humans can walk bent over at the waist for some time, but it begins to hurt. A similar strain is present for chimps and gorillas walking upright. Their opposable thumbs are also very poorly designed compared to how ours work for grasping and holding. But as I said: It makes no difference: My point was that ANY body form with human level intelligence will design tools, furniture, residences and machines to be easy for THEM to use with whatever they've got.

Comment: I didn't say that it was their preferred method of locomotion. I said that they *can* do it, and [they actually *do* move upright](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJSYQ9l-Xdw) in the wild when [it suits them](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NAFwd-4CkMM). Just like we *can* climb trees and walk on all fours when needed.

Comment: @AlexP What is the point of your insistence? The paragraph talks about ***body forms*** not making a difference. it does not refer to ***only*** apes. It is a general logical observation backed up by science. Making it apply ONLY to apes is an incorrect assumption, it could (and did) apply just as much to corvids, dolphins, elephants and octopi, all of which show SOME more advanced problem solving abilities.

Comment: Sorry Amadeus, this Answer is completely bogus. While it is true our development was (most likely) sparked by "a singular mutation that occurred perhaps 200,000 years ago", I beg to differ on the following points: 1) mutation concerned language, not cunning. 2) no mutation involving homeobox genes (in Chordate) concerns a single aspect (no way to genetic engineer a single change). 3) many more evolutionary (anatomic) adjustments were necessary before success. 4) mutation didn't "spread like wildfire" as Hominids were close to extinction at least twice. 5) advantage was social, not individual.

Comment: @ZioByte That is completely bogus. 1) Mutation concerned the brain and ability to think recursively, language followed from that. Complex language is possible with sign and signal only, as proven in signing apes. It isn't necessary without a complex planning mentality: That comes first. 2) I did not say homeobox, and not all brain genes are mapped. 3) The crucial change is long term abstraction and planning ability, allowing ***invention:*** traps, tools, shelter, use of fire, religion, planting.  4) It undoubtedly did spread like wildfire throughout the human population, regardless of size.

Comment: @ZioByte Speech and language would do animals no good if they cannot plan more than a few hours ahead. In numerous experiments that seems to be true of the apes, even for their most coveted rewards they cannot learn to take a simple action to receive that reward eight hours later.They have long term **memories**, but zero long term imagination or planning, and without the latter no civilization is possible. That imagination/planning/future-simulation may have come by degrees, but the 1st installments had to come before any civilization. Dogs + **just** language would not build a civilization.

Comment: @Amadeus: language is exactly what enables you to plan ahead. It also gives you episodic memory. AFAIK (actually there's still some debate on that) episodic memory is (mostly) memory of the *narration* of some event. Language is what fixes some plan in place when the sensorial stimulus is gone as it can recreate it at will. Language *is* the difference. Dogs+Language wouldn't be dogs anymore and, yes, they would create *some* civilization. All marvelous *inventions* stem from fact humans can describe what to do and not just show. Snowballing took time, but built on and on, till today.

Comment: @ZioByte No. Language represents mental abstractions and the mental ability for abstract thought came first. Language is a tool and a reflection of thought, it doesn't CAUSE thought. I have an autistic grandson and know several autistic children that can use words to get some things they want: They would never build a civilization because their **thinking** is impaired. Never. Patients with Alzheimer's speak fine but would never build a civilization, they cannot plan ahead. Like chimps and gorillas, they lose track of what they were thinking and wander off. Language is a result, not the key.

Comment: @Amadeus: sorry, I do not agree (but I will drop the matter as this is not the right place for such a discussion). IM(NS)HO our conscience is nothing else than internal narration. Many animals are capable of complex and cunning behavior. What makes us stand apart is capability of retaining and transmitting knowledge. Use words to get what you want is not "language", any cat or dog can do it just fine. I will agree the two things are related, but mental abstractions (mirror neurons) are present in many mammals (and not only), but the ability to *represent* them in internal dialogue is different

Comment: @ZioByte People conceive of ideas, inventions and plans all the time that it takes them time to express in words; which proves they did not COME from words. Words and consciousness communicate ideas, they are not the origin of them. The same is true for animals that have no language: Corvids solve complex puzzles and understand machines with no language, and thus no internal dialogue. Thoughts are not language, the abstract language is triggered by thoughts and the internal dialogue occurs in the **wake** of thoughts. Imagine the shape of a car's crankshaft: You won't do that with words.

Comment: @Amadeus: to "conceive of ideas" is a *linguistic* process. Without language you have to restart building with each new generation. Sorry, we seem unable to understand each other. You *cannot* have an "idea" without a language (but you can use a language without any idea of what you're saying). I consider the discussion ended here.

Comment: @ZioByte I will consider it ended with my answer: Somebody invented a crankshaft without the word "crankshaft". The ideas of using levers or flotation to solve **original** puzzles is proven to be used by birds and apes with zero language. Ideas and inventions do not depend on language or any linguistic process whatsoever, or ***language itself*** would never have been invented. Language assigns labels to abstract mental models, like what constitutes a "horse", and long before we assigned such labels we had to develop those abstract models. You are just wrong, both logically and factually.

Answer (score 2):

As question is posted answer is "NO".

Apes, as we have them in real Earth, cannot "take the place of humans".

In spite of having a genome 98+% equal to humans chimpanzee still lack that 2% enabling them to fill the gap.

The "gap" being ability to devise and use effectively a complex language capable to describe objects not previously known to listener (many animals are able to associate sounds to *known* objects/actions/situations, but that is not enough to trigger "civilization").

Of course, given a few hundred thousand years (a very short time, as evolution goes), some of the higher primates could evolve into *something* "human-like", but:

- Such an evolved ape wouldn't be an ape anymore, just like we aren't.
- Such an evolution is bound to touch other aspects of the "new ape", not only its brain.
- It is absolutely unlikely several different species would evolve "in parallel", just like it happened in the past: one branch evolved while the others took different directions.
- Having a world where all different species of apes "become intelligent" without any other physical changes is absolutely unrealistic.

Comment: We *are* apes, specifically apes adapted for running. The language, focused intelligence etc. came later, and did not change our physique very much: initially we were ordinary great apes, adapted for living and hunting in the savannah.

Comment: @AlexP: we also are chordate and mammals, but the fact has nothing to do with OP. Our physique changed a lot in the last few hundred thousand years, but the real change was the brain circuitry enabling us to communicate complex concepts igniting cultural evolution, the same that's fueling today's snowballing.

Comment: Yeah, my line of thinking: if current other Apes are to produce civilization after us, they'd evolve into something very resembling of homo-sapiens first. At which point they are no longer the Apes we know.

Comment: @NickDzink: not necessarily resembling Homo Sapiens, but surely note being an "ape" either. Stress should go to fact *some* ape specie *could* evolve (given enough time); having *all* ape species to evolve in parallel is absolutely unbelievable. Another point to ponder is fact humans were very close to extinction several times, which means early developments were not immediately useful (or, at least *that* useful). NOTE: Idea that someone can use genetic engineering to induce a "mutation in the brain" without changing anything else is just fiction with no resemblance to reality.

Answer (score 0):

**No**

Is it possible for non-human apes to take the place of humans?
Well eventually after millions of years of evolution yes. Otherwise no.

Is it possible for non-human apes to discover fire, agriculture and advanced civilization? No. Non-human apes do not have sufficient intellect and intelligence.

Apes in space? No with the exception of Ham the Chimpanzee who did travel in space in the 1960’s, but was sent there by NASA. Needless to say Ham played no part in the rocket science program that put him into space.

Could humans take the place of apes?
Not really. Although humans can climb in trees they are not adapted for a life in the tree canopy and would have no desire to live there.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Would it be possible for non-human apes such as chimpanzees, gorillas , and orangutans to take the place of humans?**

   Specifically, chimpanzees. Orangs and gorillas are much too specialized, or well-adapted, to their lifestyles. But chimpanzees, they are generalists just like us, so yes, maybe, if somehow humans disappeared from Earth.

   Chimpanzees are very close to us, biologically speaking, so close that some zoologists argued in favor of sinking the genus *Pan* into *Homo*; for a popular treatment, see the Jared Diamond's famous book [*The Third Chimpanzee*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Third_Chimpanzee) (that being *H. sapiens*, and the other two being of course *P. troglodytes* and *P. paniscus*).

   But unless all humans disappear from Earth chimpanzees don't have a chance. This is a clear case where being there first counts, and winner takes it all; [Hilaire Belloc](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Hilaire_Belloc)'s witty rhime fits, although he was not referring to chimpanzees: *"whatever happens, we have got the Maxim gun, and they have not"*.
2. **Like in the 1968 movie “Planet of the apes”, would it be possible for apes to discover fire, agriculture and create complex civilization?**

   It is *certainly* possible, because they already did it. We *are* apes.

   Humans and chimpanzees began splitting up some 8 million years ago and they finally split up some 4 million years ago; it seems that for a very long time the two lineages remained close enough to allow occasional mating and gene transfer. After our lineage became fully independent it took our ancestors about 4 million years to discover agriculture and set up the conditions for rapid cultural development.

   [There are 300,000 chimpanzees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_chimpanzee#Status_and_conservation) on Earth and 7,500,000,000 humans; that means that even if some war or disease kills 99.99% of humans  *there will still be more humans than chimpanzees*; humans, who already have language and technology (be it 19th century technology) will recover fast enough. As long as humans are not wiped out completely chimpanzees don't stand a chance.
3. **Would they be able to communicate like we do? In a few thousand years would it be possible for these apes to be able to travel through space?**

   They cannot communicate as we do. We know, we have tried to teach them. If humans disappeared, it would probably take the descendants of chimpanzees anywhere between half a million to 4 million years to reach the level of civilization humans had at the dawn of history; the rest will come very much quicker. But they won't be chimpanzees: they will be a new species *descended* from chimpanzees.
4. **Also, in this world could humans take the place of modern day apes? Climbing in trees and those sorts of things.**

   Humans are apes adapted for running; while we *can* climb trees, like any other ape, we do it clumsily and only if we absolutely must. The only great apes strongly adapted for living in trees are the orangs; gorillas are ground apes, like us, much too heavy to climb trees past adolescence.

   If humans are not completely wiped out then chimpanzees won't have the respite to evolve into a technological species; so no, sorry, but a world with both humans and technological chimpanzees is very unlikely.

Comment: New franchise of PotA conviniently makes humans progressively more retarded(in biological sense) with the same virus that makes other apes smarter. So that kinda rules out civilisation recovery.